# Is replacing one meal a day with nuts bad for health in long term?

Tags: nutrition, diet

I realised that replacing one meal a day (namely lunch) with a bag of mixed nuts (~200g) would be great for me for several reasons:

- no cooking required
- reasonably cheap
- can eat while on-the-go
- nuts keep you full for a long time
- low in sugar, high in fiber and protein

I know that nuts are also high in fat, however it isn't saturated fat. Is this high amount of fat bad in the long term? Is there another reason why having 200 g nuts as a single food at one meal is a bad idea?

Comment: It's high in Omega-3 fats, so that's good especially if you also reduce your cooking oil intake at dinner, but unfortunately nuts are not cheap once you start to eat hundreds of grams per day.

Comment: You could have an apple too on some days, though they are not exactly cheap anymore. Cut it up if you want, pack in a regular container with ice, you can drink the water later and eat the apple with your nuts.https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/267290.php

Comment: What exactly is the question here!

Comment: This article has some good information, it happens to be about nuts and renal disease, but it contains a lot of  information you may find interesting about the varieties of nuts. https://www.jrnjournal.org/article/S1051-2276(16)30192-3/fulltext

Comment: @GrahamChiu, the question is clear to me: Is eating 200 g of nuts as a single food at one meal bad on long term? So, I think, the close votes could be retracted.

Comment: @Jan I haven't voted on this question but if the question is clear to you, how about editing it to make it clear to the rest of us; in particular those who voted to close the question?

Comment: OK; I edited it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are reasons why eating 200 g of nuts as the sole food at one meal could be questionable:

- [200 g of dry roasted mixed nuts](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3176/2) contains 1188 Calories. This is about half of daily calories coming from a single food, which sounds like a lack of food diversity.
- Nuts have very high omega-6/omega-3 ratio: 55:1, which might be pro-inflammatory. Regarding omega-6 PUFA, there is controversy whether their effects are pro- or anti-inflammatory. ([PubMed, 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26745681))
- The idea to spare some time by eating the food on the go sounds attractive, but it is also stressful; I believe one should sit down and eat in peace for optimal digestion.
- Nuts are high in fats, so they [stay a long time in the stomach](http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/hbooks/pathphys/digestion/stomach/emptying.html), which can give a prolonged heavy feeling after eating.

Comment: Walnuts have a good Omega-3/Omega-6 ratio

Comment: The OP mentioned "a bag of mixed nuts." [Peanuts](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/legumes-and-legume-products/4448/2) omega-6/omega-3 ratio = 5630/1 ! [Hazelnuts](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3116/2) = 90/1. [Brazil nuts](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3091/2) = 1142/1.

Comment: That citation is not authored by PubMed...

Comment: I did not say it is. But PubMed urls are very stable and they do not get changed as the urls of medical magazines with original articles often do.